# Combined values in Pie chart issue in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, charts, pie-chart

I am drawing a Pie chart in Android using MPAndroidChart. I have two different array list for different teams and need to show both list in combined form on Pie chart. Now i'm having an issue while drawing data on chart.

[image]

As you can see in screenshot "caught" type is showing 2 time with different values in chart. How to combine both of them with sum of their respective values?

Comment: Are you using a cricket api

Comment: not using cricket api

Comment: can you share the data of the array?